# If Statement to check time in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, time

I need to create an if statement to check time in excel. For instance if time is between

00:00:01 to 06:00:00 I give a value of 1
if time is 06:00:01 to 12:00:00 I give a value of 2
if time is 12:00:01 to 18:00:00 I give a value of 3
and if time is 18:00:01 to 00:00:00 I give a value of 4

Any ideas how I should implement this?

Comment: are you wanting to use the Current time on your computer, or a time in a cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the time is in cell A1, you could use:

```
=CEILING(A1/0.25,1)
```

It worked on some sample data for me:

```
12:01:03        3
18:19:00        4
00:00:01        1
```

The above works because dates are actually numbers in Excel, and 1 unit represents 1 day. So naturally, if you divide 1 day by 4, you get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel Worksheet formula like shown below (it reads the system time using function NOW()):

```
=IF(HOUR(NOW())>18,4,IF(HOUR(NOW())>12,3,IF(HOUR(NOW())>6,2,1)))
```

If HOUR is already given in, for e.g., column A1, then use a simplified formula:

```
=IF(A1>18,4,IF(A1>12,3,IF(A1>6,2,1)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
=TEXT(IF(INT(TEXT(A1,"[m]"))<=360,1,IF(INT(TEXT(A1,"[m]"))<=720,2,IF(INT(TEXT(A1,"[m]"))<=1080,3,IF(INT(TEXT(A1,"[m]"))<=1440,4,"")))),"#")
```

Comment: @Xupla Alternatively you can try this one.